# mongoose: using array indices similar to data fields in the $in operator

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If my schema was something like this,

```
index_array: [Number],
data_array: [{val: Number}]
```

with data similar to,

```
index_array: [1,2],
data_array: [{val: 1231},{val: 1092},{va: 0902}]
```

is there anyway i can form a query to extract the elements in data array, that matches the indices specified in the index array?

in above case i should get

```
data_array: [{val: 1092},{va: 0902}]
```

I understand i can do this after i retrieve the document, but is there anyway to do this on the server itself?